# Вывод цифровой клавиатуры в maskedInput PHP Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Ребят, вот есть у меня поле формы, которое рендерится виджетом MaskedInput (Yii2). Хотелось бы по фокусу на мобильных выводить только цифровую клаву. Если в options передаю type => number и pattern => "[0-9]*", то не отрабатывает маска.

```
<?php
    echo MaskedInput::widget([
        'name' => 'phone',
        'value' => ($phone ? "+7 " . $phone : ''),
        'mask' => '+7 (999) 999-99-99',
        'options' => array('class' => 'is-validation ' . $prefix . 'phone',
                                    'data-type' => '123phone',
                                    'data-action' => '1',
                                    'data-name' => 'Номер телефона',
                                    'id' => $prefix . 'phone')
      );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для телефонов указывайте

```
'type' => 'tel'
```